# Scandir Recursive to Json with multidimensionnal "array"

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to list my folders and files and get them in a json_encode with a specific structure.
My function is working but I can't manage to get my JSON as I want.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```php
function myScandirRecursive($dir) {
    $result = array();
    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))  {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)){
                $result["name"][$value] = myScandirRecursive($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
            } else {
                $result["files"][] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

echo json_encode(myScandirRecursive("my_main_folder"))
```

The result in JSON :

```
{
  "files": {
    "file.html",
    "file.php"
  },
  "name": {
    "subFolder1": {
      "files": [
        "file.mp4",
        "file.txt"
      ],
      "name": {
        "subSubFolder": {
          "files": [
            "test"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "subFolder2": {
      "files": [
        "file.png"
      ],
      "name": {
        "subSubFolder": {
          "files": [
            "file.css",
            "file.html",
            "file.php",
            "file.txt"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output expected:

```json
  
  "my_main_folder": {
    "name" : "subFolder1",
   {
    "files": {
        "title": "file.mp4",
        "tilte": "file.txt"
      }
   },
   
    "name": "subFolder2",
   {
     "files": {
        "tilte": "file.png", 
      }
      "name": "SubSubFolder",
    {
      "files": {
          "title": "file.css",
          "title": "file.html",
          "title": "file.php",
          "title": "file.txt"
        }
    }
   }
}
```

I need that structure to be able to use my JSON easily in javascript. Anyone could help me please ?

Comment: What you have currently shown as your expected output, is not even valid JSON.

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner! I edited the post. Is it better ?

Comment: No, still not valid JSON, now it just starts with `"my_main_folder": {` out of nowhere.

Comment: Also you have repeated fields like "name" (on the folder level) and "title" (on the files level). This kind of structure is not _valid_ JSON ... To explain somehow -  it's like in PHP arrays - if you use the same name for multiple fields - the later "title" overwrites the earliers.